# How to handle change the appearance of 'categories' box on dashboard?

Tags: menus, hooks, dashboard

I have a site with hundreds of categories, and when I come to edit some menu on `wp-admin/nav-menus.php` it is really difficult, because in the `categories` box  there a few pages, with something like 20 categories names on each page, so I can not see all the categories. (Also I use a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/intuitive-category-checklist/screenshots/) that presents the category list (on dashboard) in a tree view, and a dividing on pages, damages the plugin activity).
So what is the way to display all the categories as one single page?

Comment: Perhaps you can try load a custom stylesheet that add height to the metabox that display the categories?

Comment: No. Because the content of other pages is not in the html code at all, e.g. when you press '2' (to go to the second page) you go to another URL.